# Return from inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

How I update x.test to have values return from inheritance ?

So I want x.test return ['test from B'', 'test from  C']

```
class A()    
    def __init__(self)    
        self.test = []
        return
    def coolThings(self):
        # do cool things here and print the new self.test
        print self.test

class B(A)    
    def __init__(self)    
        A.__init__(self)
        return

    def doSomething(self)    
        self.test.append('test from B')

class C(A)    
    def __init__(self)    
        A.__init__(self)
        return
    def doAnotherthing(self)    
        self.test.append('test from  C') 
--

In [575]     x = A()  

In [576]     y = B()

In [577]     z = c()


In [582]     y.doSomething()

In [583]     z.doAnotherthing()

In [584]     x.test
Out[584]     []

In [585]     y.test
Out[585]     ['test B']

In [586]     z.test
Out[586]     ['test C']

x.coolThings()
??
```

So again How update x.test to have ['test from B'', 'test from  C']

But again how can I mantain self.test in all inheritance? So If I call z.test after y.doSomething() I would like to have ['test from B']

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here: inheritance, and static data

You have a static data issue.  If you want all instances of A and all instances of its children to share a TEST attribute, make it static on the class like this:

```
class A(object):
    test = []

    def coolThings(self):
        # do cool things here and print the new self.test
        print self.test
```

Inheritance is a different animal.  Inheritance just lets you give all children of A copies of A's methods.  This is not about sharing data, it's about sharing/extending functionality.

Comment: You save my day! I didnt have time enough to debug but seens works like a charme

    class A()    
        test = []
 def coolThings(self):
     print self.test

    class B(A)    
        def __init__(self)
     self.test = A.test 
            A.__init__(self)
            return

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance creates relationships between classes, not objects. In your example the classes (`A`, `B` and `C`) are related, but the objects (`x`, `y` and `z`) are not.

Tell us what you're trying to do, and we should be able to help you come up with a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance work the other way, you can't have a base class compound statements from inherited classes.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish but to have separate inherited objects influence the base class, you might use class variables but keep in mind all instances will now have the same test value in this case.

```
class A():
    test = []

    def coolThings(self):
        print test

class B(A):
    def doSomething(self):
        A.test.append('test from B')
```

I repeat again, **ALL instances of A and B for that matter will have the same value for test.**

Comment: Also, x, y and z are separate objects: calling a method of one won't change the others. Try doing `z.test`.

Comment: Yes thanks, like beer_monk said probably "it's about sharing/extending functionality" it is working now! thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance doesn't work like that. Try this way:

```
x = C()
x.doSomething()
x.doAnotherThing()
x.test
```

Comment: x won't have access to doSomething as it is defined in B.